# Circle Intercepting An Ellipse

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

A circle of radius $r$ passes through both foci of, and exactly four points on, the ellipse with equation $x^2+16y^2=16$. The set of all possible values of $r$ is an interval $[a,b)$. What is $a+b$?

To find the value of the radius of the circle is quite easy. This is just half the distance from the two foci of the ellipse which are $(\sqrt{-15},0)$ and $(\sqrt{15},0)$, or $\sqrt{15}$.

I have no way to find $b$. Please help.

Note: I'm still in high school, so don't expect much from me.

Comment: "exactly four points on" is a pretty important constraint. Consider the circle that passes through the foci and is tangent to the given ellipse.

Comment: Aha! It's the limiting case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the focii of the ellipse, which are $(-\sqrt{15}, 0)$ and $(\sqrt{15}, 0)$

- **Minimum** radius will be when circle's centre is at $(0,0)$, that is, $\min(r) = \sqrt{15}$,
  This is minimum as the focal points lie diametrically opposite to each other on circle.
- For **maximum**, consider the other boundary line condition, as said by JM.
  If the radius is so large that the circle passing through focii becomes tangent to ellipse, then by pythagorous theorem:
  $$(r-1)^2 + 15 = r^2$$
  From which we get $r = 8$

---

**PS**: Dude I too am in high school. Cheers!

Comment: I'm sorry, but those points are not the foci of the ellipse.

Comment: But, the OP already claims to have found a different $r$ from that of yours.

Comment: @Rohan yes I made a mistake while finding focii.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here is an animation of the family of circles that satisfy the criteria of the problem:

[image]

For those with *Mathematica*, an interactive form of this animation can be produced with the following command:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[
   {{4 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, Sqrt[d^2 + 15] {Cos[t], Sin[t]} + {0, d}},
   {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}],
  Graphics[{Red, Disk[#, .1] & /@ ({#[[1]] 4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[105 - d^2
      + #[[2]] d Sqrt[15 + d^2]], -d + #[[2]] Sqrt[15 + d^2]}/15
      & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2]), Blue, Disk[{Sqrt[15], 0}, .05],
      Disk[{-Sqrt[15], 0}, .05], Orange, Disk[{0, d}, 0.1],
      Opacity[0.5], Line[{{Sqrt[15], 0}, {0, d}, {-Sqrt[15], 0}}]}]],
  {d, -7, 7}]
```

Comment: Nice animation! With what program did you make it?

Comment: @StackTD *Mathematica* v10.

Comment: Alright, thanks (and +1).

Comment: Wow wee. That is amazing.